# Custom FileHandler - Get Loged User

Tags: dotnetnuke

I created custom file handler for PDF files and registered it to DotNetNuke and it works OK.

But now I also need to get Current User inside serving pdf,
but don't know how.

I tried with this code inside BeginProcessRequest:

```
DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.Instance.GetCurrentUserInfo()
```

but it is always **NULL**

My code for AsyncHandler:

```
public class Code : IHttpAsyncHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
        AsynchOperation asynch = new AsynchOperation(cb, context, extraData);
        asynch.StartAsyncWork();
        return asynch;
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because your handler isn't running as part of the DNN pipeline thus all the DNN goodness doesn't come through (like if your module didn't use PortalModuleBase).

If you're calling off to get a PDF - you should also pass PortalId and UserId as querystring params or part of the request header - so you can pull the userinfo you need by UserId and portal id.

Comment: thanks for helping, I posted the solution that work for me, just don't know if this is really secure

Answer (score 0):

I added reference to DotNetNuke.dll and change the code:

```
public class Code : IHttpAsyncHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

    public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
        // to get user name
        var uname = context.User.Identity.Name; 
        // to populate user roles
        var userRoles = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetUserByName(uname).Roles;

        AsynchOperation asynch = new AsynchOperation(cb, context, extraData);
        asynch.StartAsyncWork();
        return asynch;
    }

    public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```